# Electrostatics - amber and cloth charge transfer

Tags: electrostatics, charge

If amber and cloth are rubbed together, it is known that some electrons are transfered from cloth to amber. In this case, cloth acquires a positive charge and amber a negative charge. If these two have opposite charge, shouldn't there be electrostatic force between these two ? So, the next time you rub these two items, shouldn't the electrons be transferred from amber to cloth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If these two have opposite charge, shouldn't there be electrostatic force between these two ?

There is.

> So, the next time you rub these two items, shouldn't the electrons be transferred from amber to cloth?

That can happen any time they are rubbed.  You have two competing effects every time the materials are in contact:

- Triboelectric effect that is driving electrons from cloth to amber
- Electrostatic fields that are driving electrons to the more positive object

When both materials are uncharged, the second effect is zero.   So the first one will tend to separate charges.   As the charge separation increases, so do electric fields between the two.   Eventually an equilibrium is reached where the charge separation cannot be increased by further rubbing.